# Cloning IIS requests

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, web-server, iis-7.5

I would like to achieve the following:
Request arrives to production machine, it is being processed and asynchronously the request is cloned and redirected to another machine (for test purposes). The response from test machine does not matter. 
 I don't want to "record" live traffic and then replay it on test machine, I'm interested in live flow of live requests.
Is it achievable?

Comment: Do you just need simple GET requests, or do you need to clone POST payload data as well?

Comment: GETs only, for now at least